# reference undefined fields in dataclass will still pass static check (pylint, pylance)

Tags: python, pylint, python-typing, python-dataclasses, pylance

Given the following sample code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Demo:
  a: int = 1

d = Demo()
d.b # b: Any
```

I don't know why static check won't report missing attribute but treating it as Any type instead. Is there any way to make it to report error?

Comment: No idea why Pylance would _not_ report this as an error. It clearly is an error and is picked up by Mypy as an `[attr-defined]` error. But I don't use Pylance, so I did not try to reproduce it.

Comment: Aren't you mixing `pylint`, `pyright` and `pylance` together? `pylance` is a microsoft's python language server and vscode extension, which uses `pyright` for type checking. `pylint` doesn't perform any typechecking at all, it's a - surprise - linter. This error does not reproduce, when I call `pyright` directly (it says `error: Cannot access member "b" for type "Demo"`, as expected). I'm voting to close as not reproducible, you can to sharing (much) more debugging details to avoid it.

Comment: I failed to make pylint work, but for the case of pylance it's just my mistake. I wasn't aware that I didn't enable typecheck in VsCode.  But I still want to know how to make pylint work as expect as pylance failed  in many other cases.

Comment: You cannot make `pylint` work as a type checker, those are different tools with different goals. And detecting undefined attributes is far more complex than plain AST or formatting rules.